# how to change the version of java from 8 to 11 on ubuntu without sudo

Tags: java, ubuntu, sudo

I am trying to switch from java version `java-8-openjdk-amd6` to `java-11-openjdk-amd6` without using `sudo` since its not allowed.

i tried the following:

```
update-alternatives --config java

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1101      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/ecj                                   143       manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1101      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1071      manual mode
* 4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode
  5            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
```

after choosing a number i am getting the error below:

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in auto mode
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link '/etc/alternatives/javac.dpkg-tmp': Permission denied
```

i there any alternative solution ?

Comment: This question more suited at [superuser of stackexchange](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate your own `PATH`. The usual suggestion is a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Add the lines to your `.bashrc` to keep through logout / reboot.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to store this lines into my `.bashrc`?